# MS SQL 2005 Client excessive memory usage

Tags: sql-server, memory

Hi I inherited the support of an MS SQL 2005 server on a Windows 2003 server and its client XP workstations running MS SQL 2005 Native client. The database is appox. 1GB in size and some of the tables contain several thousand records.

The problem I now have is that when the client (OLEDB) applications access the server to create an new customer for example their memory usage peaks out at 1.23GB whilst performing the task. 
On some workstations they simply run out out memory and the operation fails. 
I have loaded an earlier much smaller copy of the database and when running that the memory usage is less then 50MB. So memory creep seems to be related to number of records in the database.
What can I do on the client workstations to determine what is using the memory and how to reduce the memory usage. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.
Arthur

Comment: It might help to do more investigation as to what sort of queries are being run. If the client is requesting all rows and plenty of columns it's likely it just needs lots of ram to complete the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the clients are on separate machines than the database (which sounds like the case here) and you can confirm through task manager or process explorer that the client app process is consuming all that memory then there is nothing you can do.  The application must be tuned or redesigned so that it doesn't bring all of the data local to the client.  There isn't anything you can do with the SQL Server configuration to prevent this.

If you're really lucky (and really know what you're doing!) then there will be some code in stored procedures or views that you might be able to get into and tweak.  This is really something for the developer to look into, though.

Comment: Thank you for answering. As you suggest I suspect its the application and the Not SQL server or its clients. I have been using Task Manager and ProcessHacker to check memory usage. I know the application uses transactions and I did wonder if these were being held in memory before being committed? Many thanks.